# Android AnimationDrawable returning null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, animationdrawable

My main objective for this is to get it to have a "button" that initially is dark and when pressed cycles through the animation of it lighting up in a clockwise direction like a progress bar. But I can't seem to get animationdrawable working at all.

I have my xml animation called squareanimation located in a drawable resource folder in the res directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="true">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/square" android:duration="210" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/square1" android:duration="210" />

</animation-list>
```

I have my ImageView in my Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.soundboard.sounds.MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/app_background">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Cowbell"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageHost"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="beep"
            android:id="@+id/beepButton"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/square" />

        </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then I have my activity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    AnimationDrawable squareanimation;
    Button beepButton;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            beepButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.beepButton);

            ImageView square = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageHost);
            square.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.squareanimation);
            squareanimation = (AnimationDrawable) square.getBackground();
    }


        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if(squareanimation == null)beepButton.setText("Not working");
                return true;
            }
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
```

*These are only snippets of my code*

Everytime I run my program no matter how many times I clean or rebuild or whatever, the program won't change squareanimation from being null. And if I do run the squareanimation.start() method it crashes the program.

My images are all in PNG format at 128px * 128px if that changes anything at all. All my Images are stored in the drawable-hdpi folder.

Answer (score 0):

I added this as an answer, so people like me who make the same mistake can find an easy fix. I just swapped to android studio from eclipse so I didn't know some of the functions of it. Story short, when creating animationDrawable xml files -right click your drawable resource folder and click add new drawable resource file. I stupidly just created a normal xml file and somehow it didn't gain the same functionality.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. Thanks!